# How to make disappear Chrome warning popup "Your password may be compromise"

Tags: google-chrome, firebase-hosting

I recently deployed a website on firebase hosting. The root page is a login page, on Chrome browser when I enter my password I get a warning popup:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/creFe.jpg)

The website is really basic, it is hosted on "firebase hosting" with the default settings, developed in react JS + formik. The domain name is from ovh.

I tried to: 
- Check the website on Google Search console
- Verify my firebase hosting settings
- Change the html login form

Any clue on how to make this popup desapear once for good?

The website is impacted is https://dealgenie.fr/

Comment: That's Chrome telling you that it's not safe to use that password anymore. Change the password to a new strong password and the messages should go away.

Comment: did you ever get this one fixed? i'm having the same problem and there is no documentation on how to fix this online (that i have found )

Comment: I had it fixed with by the Firebase support. Apparently Chrome might mistakenly show the warning because one of the sites listed in the SSL certificate was reported on SafeBrowsing. You can verify it  here => https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search?url=dealgenie.fr. Also, apparently the SSL certificates are shared, and since I'm in a Blaze plan they gave me a dedicated certificate. Sorry it's all I understood.